# how to calculate no of client support by .net server or WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, client-server, remoting

I want to know how we can find out maximum no of client can be supported by server written in .NET. This server could be anything like WCF service or .NET remoting etc.

What is the way or guidelines we can use to to find no of supported client in this case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start a load testing tool and turn it up until your service fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on a large number of factors. Things you may want to consider: server hardware, supporting infrastructure, Application logic and concurrency

With a web service like wcf, the metric you are looking for is the number of requests/s that a server can handle, which can be used to derive a number of unique clients based on an expected workload per client.

Of the factors listed, the biggest impact will  certainly be the application logic that is being coded. Any server framework can vary wildly in performance from the same traffic. The best way to estimate the number of clients that can be supported would be to take an aggregrate workload of many users, determine the traffic patterns for clients, and simulate traffic for an increasing number of operations until performance degrades to a level you are comfortable with.

There are simply too many factors to give a straight answer. Sever .NET applications fail under a small load, while stackoverflow is written with .NET and is run on a very small number of servers.